# Mutually inclusive set properties

Tags: statistics

One of my courses in university touches briefly on statistics; I took introductory statistics a few years back, and I would say I am quite knowledgable, but I have a couple of questions.

In the course, the professor was laying out the basic statistics between mutually **exclusive** events, and then moved onto sets which the intersection of which is not null. He asked a question regarding two subsets, *A* & *B* which are in a set *Ω*. Sets A and B share some elements, and he asked us what that means, I stated that it should mean that the intersection of A and B, say C, is mutually inclusive with A and B, he said that mutually inclusive don't exist mathematically but only linguistically.

Can someone please explain that to me?
A further thought I had was surely a set *A* is mutually inclusive with itself?

Comment: Never heard that phrase, mathematically. I suppose it would mean $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$, so $A=B$.  Better to just say "equal".